# Factoring 3 unknown expressions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

I'm given a word problem that's as follows:

A, B, C each think of expression that is fraction with $1$ as a numerator and a constant integer times some power of $x$ as a denominator.

The simplest common denominator between A and B expresssions is $4x^{2}$.

The simplest common denominator between B and C expresssions is $12x^{3}$.

The simplest common denominator between A and C expresssions is $6x^{3}$.

Find all possible expressions that could be C's expressions.

How do I even begin to reason about this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than phrasing with fractions... letting $a,b,c$ be the denominators of $A,B,C$ respectively the problem is saying that $\text{lcm}(a,b)=4x^2, \text{lcm}(b,c)=12x^3$ and $\text{lcm}(a,c)=6x^3$.

You should be able to reason that $a$ must be one of $1,2,4,x,2x,4x,x^2,2x^2,4x^2$ since these are the possible factors of $\text{lcm}(a,b)=4x^2$.  Similarly for $b$.

Meanwhile, we notice that since $\text{lcm}(b,c)$ and $\text{lcm}(a,c)$ both have $x^3$ in it that $c$ must be a multiple of $x^3$ since had it been a multiple of $x^4$ or higher the $\text{lcm}$ would have been with at least as large an exponent as well while on the other hand had $c$ been a multiple of $x^2$ or lower then the $\text{lcm}$ would not have needed an $x^3$...

Further, we notice that since $\text{lcm}(a,b)$ did not have a factor of $3$ it must be that neither $a$ nor $b$ have a factor of $3$ in them but $\text{lcm}(a,c)$ and $\text{lcm}(b,c)$ both have a factor of $3$, implying that $c$ must have a factor of $3$ present.

Putting all of this together, we find that $a,b,c$ must be one of the following:

$$a=2x^2,b=4x^2,c=3x^3$$

$$a=x^2,b=4x^2,c=6x^3$$

$$a=2x^2,b=4x, c=3x^3$$

$$\vdots$$

and so on...  where $b$ is one of $4, 4x, 4x^2$, and $a$ is one of $1,2,x,2x,x^2,2x^2$, and at least one of them being a multiple of $x^2$ while $c$ is either $6x^3$ or $3x^3$.

Comment: Can you demonstrate why $b$ must at least be a multiple of $4$. Isn't this commutative and since $a$ and $b$ share the same common factor, either one of them should be at least multiple of 4? Sorry, don't quiet understand the last part.

Comment: @Vocaloidas since $c$ is a factor of $6x^3$ we know that the integer coefficient of $c$ must be either $6,3,2,1$.  Since $\text{lcm}(b,c)=12x^3$ we know that at least one of $b,c$ must be a multiple of $4$.  Since it can't be $c$, it must be $b$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The simplest common denominator between A and B expresssions is $4x^2$ implies that their denominators is one of the following sets:

$$ \{ 1, 4x^2 \}, \{ 2, 4x^2 \}, \{ 4 , 4x^2 \}, \\
\{ x, 4x^2 \} , \{ 2x, 4x^2 \} , \{ 4x, 4x^2 \} , \\
\{ x^2, 4x^2 \} , \{ 2x^2, 4x^2 \} , \{ 4x^2, 4x^2 \} \\
\{ 4, 2x^2 \} , \{ 4, x^2 \} $$

---

Hint: The denominator of $C$ must be a factor of $6x^3$ and also of $12x^3$.